# "Person.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am writing a small data migration to create UserProfiles for existing Django users who dont have UserProfiles.

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    for user in User.objects.all():
        try:
            person = user.get_profile()
        except:
            newperson = orm.Person(user=user)
            newperson.save()
```

but I keep getting

```
"Person.user" must be a "User" instance
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing migrations in South you don't have to use the models classes directly, but the frozen ones. In the example above, you're likely trying to assign a current *User* object to a frozen *Person* one. The frozen *Person* objects expects a frozen *User* object.

You need to rewrite it as follows:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    for user in orm['auth.User'].objects.all():
        try:
            # cannot use user.get_profile() because it is not available in the frozen model
            person = orm.Person.get(user=user)  
        except:
            newperson = orm.Person(user=user)
            newperson.save()
```

See http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html#accessing-the-orm

BTW I advise you not to use a bare *except* but *except SomeException* to be more robust.

Comment: i forgot that django's user model is not inside my app.

Comment: by the way: now i am getting ``User object has no attribute 'get_profile' `` why is it?

Comment: if i print the ``user`` inside a loop, i get ``User Object`` and not ``[<User>: user]`` or so. i think, this is why i am getting the error above, right?

Comment: Yes, the custom model methods are not frozen, you will have to recreate the code yourself. See http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html#rationale-behind-the-serialisation

I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: awesome, i also just read about this: ``"The only caveat is that you won’t have access to any custom methods or managers on your models, as they’re not preserved as part of the freezing process (there’s no way to do this generally);"``